# How to process a list in parallel in Python?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I wrote code like this:

```
def process(data):
   #create file using data

all = ["data1", "data2", "data3"]
```

I want to execute process function on my all list in parallel, because they are creating small files so I am not concerned about disk write but the processing takes long, so I want to use all of my cores.

How can I do this using default modules in python 2.7?

Comment: Help you to search next time, keywords: `multiprocessing python map`. Then you can easily find solution from Google.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming CPython and the [GIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294382/what-is-the-global-interpreter-lock-gil-in-cpython) here.

If your task is I/O bound, in general, threading may be more efficient since the threads are simply dumping work on the operating system and idling until the I/O operation finishes. Spawning processes is a heavy way to babysit I/O.

However, most file systems aren't concurrent, so using multithreading or multiprocessing *may* not be any faster than synchronous writes.

Nonetheless, here's a contrived example of [`multiprocessing.Pool.map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) which may help with your CPU-bound work:

```
from multiprocessing import cpu_count, Pool

def process(data):
    # best to do heavy CPU-bound work here...

    # file write for demonstration
    with open("%s.txt" % data, "w") as f:
        f.write(data)

    # example of returning a result to the map
    return data.upper()
      
tasks = ["data1", "data2", "data3"]
pool = Pool(cpu_count() - 1)
print(pool.map(process, tasks))
```

A similar setup for threading can be found in [`concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor).

As an aside, `all` is a builtin function and isn't a great variable name choice.

Answer (score 7):

Or:

```
from threading import Thread

def process(data):
    print("processing {}".format(data))

l= ["data1", "data2", "data3"]

for task in l:
    t = Thread(target=process, args=(task,))
    t.start()
```

Or (only python version > 3.6.0):

```
from threading import Thread

def process(data):
    print(f"processing {data}")

l= ["data1", "data2", "data3"]

for task in l:
    t = Thread(target=process, args=(task,))
    t.start()
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a template of using `multiprocessing`, hope helpful.

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool

def process(data):
    print("processing {}".format(data))
alldata = ["data1", "data2", "data3"]

pool = ThreadPool()

results = pool.map(process, alldata)

pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Comment: OP says "I want to use all of my cores". `ThreadPool` won't use more than one core.