# How to parellelize a nested for loop in function with multiple arguments

Tags: python, parallel-processing

I'm trying to solve the minimum vertex cover problem using the Brute-Force Approach, basically trying every combination of edges of a graph to find the minimum.

I have a nested for loop that I want to run parallel

Say I have the following code so far:

```
def brute_force_MVC(vertices, edges):
    bin_input=["000","001","010","011","100","101","110","111"]
    for case in bin_input:
        for i, vertex in enumerate(vertices):
            if case[i]:
                #do stuff
                for edge in edges:
                   #do more stuff
```

is there a way to parallelize this? instead of running each case one after the other, could i run them parallel? Would that speed things up?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing

Comment: As Rishav mentioned, you should use mutiprocessing to run parallel

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to process a list in parallel in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51814897/how-to-process-a-list-in-parallel-in-python)

Comment: the problem is, I have multiple inputs on my function, all the documentation is for 1 input functions, including the thread posted above.

Comment: @canecse Group your inputs into tuples.

Comment: Even with a tuple, i'm still passing two arguments to the function: the bin_input and the tuples. The documentation for the library you posted shows parallel processing for 1 argument.  
@rishav could you perhaps provide a pseudocode for your suggestion?