# How to limit and queue up processes in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, process, parallel-processing, python-3.6

Lets say I have 10000 tasks at hand. How can I process them in parallel, running precisely 8 processes at any time? The moment a task is finished, the next task should be fetched for execution immediately.

```
for e in arr:
   pr=Process(target=execute, args=(q,e))
   pr.start()
   pr.join()
```

I want to do this because my CPU has only 8 hardware threads. Swarming it with 10000 tasks at once will slow down the overall computation due to the switching overhead. My memory is also limited.

(***Edit***: This is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51814897/how-to-process-a-list-in-parallel-in-python) as I am not asking how to fork a process.)

Comment: Look at the [Pool classes in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to process a list in parallel in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51814897/how-to-process-a-list-in-parallel-in-python)

Comment: I don't think it is a duplicate of that question, as I am not asking how to fork a process. Anyway, Pool is probably the solution to my problem. Thanks, James!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Pool to work here I need to call get() too.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
pl=[]
pool = Pool(8)
for e in arr:
   pl.append(pool.apply_async(execute, (e))
for pl2 in pl: pl2.get()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you split the "for" loop for join statement your problem might be solved. Right now you start a fork and want the result to come back and go do another fork process. And no fork is closed right now.

```
for e in arr:
   pr=Process(target=execute, args=(q,e))
   pr.start()

for e in arr: 
   pr.join()
```

Or just go with pool and map functions.

Comment: I am going for Pool.