# Parallelizing, Multiprocessing, CSV writer

Tags: python, csv, batch-processing, concurrent.futures, timeoutexception

I have a huge list of strings called `term_list` that I process one-by-one in a function called `run_mappers()`. One of the args is a `csv_writer` object. I append results to a list called `from_mapper` in the function. I write that list to a csv file using the `csv_writer` object. In my scouring for help, I read that multiprocessing module is not recommended for csv writing because it it pickles and csv_writer objects can't be pickled (can't find reference for this now in my billion tabs open on my desktop). I am not sure if multiprocessing is best suited for my task anyway.

```
def run_mappers(individual_string, other_args, csv_writer):
   # long processing code goes here, ending up with processed_result 
   from_mapper.append(processed_result)
   csv_writer.writerow(processed_result)
```

I want to speed up processing of this huge list, but am trying to control for memory usage by splitting the list into batches to process (term_list_batch). So I try:

```
def parallelize_mappers(term_list_batch, other_args, csv_writer):
    
    future_to_term = {}
    terms_left = len(term_list_batch)

    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=6) as executor:
        future_to_term = {executor.submit(run_mappers, term_list_batch, other_args, csv_writer): term for term in term_list_batch}
        try:
            for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_term, timeout=180): # timeout after 3 min
                term = future_to_term[future]
                try:
                    result = future.result()
                    # Process result if needed
                except Exception as exc:
                    print(f"Job {term} generated an exception: {exc}")
                finally:
                    terms_left -= 1
                    if terms_left % 10 == 0:
                        gc.collect()
                        time.sleep(2)
        except concurrent.futures.TimeoutError:
            print("Timeout occurred while processing futures")
            for key, future in future_to_term.items():
                if key not in results:
                    future.cancel()
```

When I get a Timeouterror, my process just hangs and I'm not sure what to do to keep moving forward in my huge term_list. I also don't want to terminate the program. I just want to keep moving through term_list, or process the next batch. If a thread fails or something, I just want to ignore the term or toss the whole thread and continue processing term_list to write as many results to the file as I can.

Amongst my many attempts to trouble-shoot, I tried something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51814897/how-to-process-a-list-in-parallel-in-python), but am posting the one above as my best shot since it crunched through a few hundred terms before stalling on me. Other tries I've had had just died, had some Runtime error, had threads deadlocking, etc.

For reference, another attempt is below:

```
def parallelize_mappers(term_list_batch, other_args, csv_writer):
    
    timeout = 120
    terminate_flag = threading.Event()

    # Create a thread for each term
    threads = []
    for term in term_list_batch:
        thread = threading.Thread(target=run_mappers, args=(term, other_args, csv_writer, terminate_flag))
        threads.append(thread)
        thread.start()

    # Wait for all threads to complete or timeout
    for thread in threads:
        thread.join(timeout)

        # If the thread is still alive, it has timed out
        if thread.is_alive():
            print("Thread {} timed out. Terminating...".format(thread.name))
            terminate_flag.set()  # Set the flag to terminate the thread
```

Then I added a `while not terminate_flag.is_set()` to the `run_mappers()` function before executing rest of processing code. But this is just unbearably slow. Thank you in advance.

Mock code to reproduce/term_list to process below:

```
term_list = ['Dementia',
 'HER2-positive Breast Cancer',
 'Stroke',
 'Hemiplegia',
 'Type 1 Diabetes',
 'Hypospadias',
 'IBD',
 'Eating',
 'Gastric Cancer',
 'Lung Cancer',
 'Carcinoid',
 'Lymphoma',
 'Psoriasis',
 'Fallopian Tube Cancer',
 'Endstage Renal Disease',
 'Healthy',
 'HRV',
 'Recurrent Small Lymphocytic Lymphoma',
 'Gastric Cancer Stage III',
 'Amputations',
 'Asthma',
 'Lymphoma',
 'Neuroblastoma',
 'Breast Cancer',
 'Healthy',
 'Asthma',
 'Carcinoma, Breast',
 'Fractures',
 'Psoriatic Arthritis',
 'ALS',
 'HIV',
 'Carcinoma of Unknown Primary',
 'Asthma',
 'Obesity',
 'Anxiety',
 'Myeloma',
 'Obesity',
 'Asthma',
 'Nursing',
 'Denture, Partial, Removable',
 'Dental Prosthesis Retention',
 'Obesity',
 'Ventricular Tachycardia',
 'Panic Disorder',
 'Schizophrenia',
 'Pain',
 'Smallpox',
 'Trauma',
 'Proteinuria',
 'Head and Neck Cancer',
 'C14',
 'Delirium',
 'Paraplegia',
 'Sarcoma',
 'Favism',
 'Cerebral Palsy',
 'Pain',
 'Signs and Symptoms, Digestive',
 'Cancer',
 'Obesity',
 'FHD',
 'Asthma',
 'Bipolar Disorder',
 'Healthy',
 'Ayerza Syndrome',
 'Obesity',
 'Healthy',
 'Focal Dystonia',
 'Colonoscopy',
 'ART',
 'Interstitial Lung Disease',
 'Schistosoma Mansoni',
 'IBD',
 'AIDS',
 'COVID-19',
 'Vaccines',
 'Beliefs',
 'SAH',
 'Gastroenteritis Escherichia Coli',
 'Immunisation',
 'Body Weight',
 'Nonalcoholic Steatohepatitis',
 'Nonalcoholic Fatty Liver Disease',
 'Prostate Cancer',
 'Covid19',
 'Sarcoma',
 'Stroke',
 'Liver Diseases',
 'Stage IV Prostate Cancer',
 'Measles',
 'Caregiver Burden',
 'Adherence, Treatment',
 'Fracture of Distal End of Radius',
 'Upper Limb Fracture',
 'Smallpox',
 'Sepsis',
 'Gonorrhea',
 'Respiratory Syncytial Virus Infections',
 'HPV',
 'Actinic Keratosis']
```

Comment: This might actually win the prize for the most over-engineered solution I have ever seen! Can you elaborate a bit on "but am trying to control for memory usage" please? Is there something really constrictive here?

Comment: Where is this list of strings? Is it already in memory?

Comment: Strings are from a pandas dataframe column, in memory. I think when I submit my term to run_mappers(), the processed result is fat in memory bc there's a java program I'm calling there, which can sometimes give me very large dictionaries that I process to get my processed_result. I'm not a computer scientist by profession, so sorry if conceptually I'm off, but this is what I think is happening when I submitted my terms without batching first - it ate up all my RAM

Comment: No need to apologise, I think I see it more clearly now. You didn't mention that you're calling a server (that I can discern) in your question. So, you have a column of strings and each string needs to be passed to the server and be processed _there_, and then you need to filter the response back _"here"_ (in python)?

Comment: Yes, I am indeed calling a server in run_mappers(). It is MetaMap.get_instance(location_on_local_machine). https://www.nlm.nih.gov/research/umls/implementation_resources/metamap.html
Then I use a python wrapper someone else wrote to actually get results from it
I also call an API here in case the java program fails. If both fail, I append None to from_mapper and move on

Comment: So yes, I have a column of strings that I pass to the server, and if it gives me None, then tries the API, and if that fails after 3 retries or it also just returns None, appends None to from_mapper. Then I try to write whatever from_mapper ends up being as  a row in the csv file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257025/discussion-between-potato-and-roganjosh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I see it, you want to parallel or multitask `run_mappers()` because this function might take a long time to finish. The CSV writing part does not need to be run in parallel because it is done relatively quick.

The first step is to redesign `run_mappers()` **NOT** to take in as parameter a CSV writer. Instead, this function should return the `processed_result`. This function might raise an exception and we will ignore the result for that thread. To be useful, I will write the errors out to `err.txt`

```py
import csv
import logging
import random
import time
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor,ThreadPoolExecutor

logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.DEBUG,
    format="%(asctime)s | %(levelname)s | %(message)s",
)

term_list = [
    "Dementia",
    # ... omitted for brevity
    "Actinic Keratosis",
]


def run_mappers(individual_string, other_args):
    # Simulate long processing time to get processed_result
    time.sleep(random.randint(1, 2))
    processed_result = [individual_string.strip(), other_args]

    # Simulate an exception
    if random.randint(1, 20) == 5:
        logging.error("%r -> failed", individual_string)
        raise (ValueError(individual_string))

    logging.debug("%r -> %r", individual_string, processed_result)
    return processed_result


def main():
    """Entry"""
    # run_mappers takes a long time, so this part is done in parallel
    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        futures = [
            executor.submit(run_mappers, term, "other-args")
            for term in term_list
        ]

    # Writing to CSV does not need to be done in parallel because
    # it is relatively quick
    logging.info("Writing to CSV")
    with open("out.csv", "w") as stream, open("err.txt", "w") as err:
        writer = csv.writer(stream)
        for future in futures:
            if future.exception():
                err.write(f"{future.exception()}\n")
            else:
                writer.writerow(future.result())
    logging.info("Done CSV")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output

```
2024-03-02 09:49:00,335 | DEBUG | 'HER2-positive Breast Cancer' -> ['HER2-positive Breast Cancer', 'other-args']
2024-03-02 09:57:55,174 | ERROR | 'Breast Cancer' -> failed
2024-03-02 09:49:11,366 | DEBUG | 'HPV' -> ['HPV', 'other-args']
...
2024-03-02 09:49:11,377 | DEBUG | 'Sepsis' -> ['Sepsis', 'other-args']
2024-03-02 09:49:11,377 | INFO | Writing to CSV
2024-03-02 09:49:11,378 | INFO | Done CSV
```

Notes

- Run this script and if the results look alright, you can add your real `run_mappers()` code
- I have no idea what `other_args` look like, so I fake it
- You might want to replace `ThreadPoolExecutor` with `ProcessPoolExecutor` and compare the timing to see which solution works more efficently

Comment: You're absolutely right about redesigning run_mappers() so that I don't a pass csv_writer object. Just not doing that solved a lot of problems.

Answer (score 0):

Hai Vu's answer seems legit and I want to test it, but I thought I'd post my current lazy workaround in case it helps. I do follow the suggestion to not pass the `csv_writer` object in `run_mappers()`, that part is definitely on the money. I just pass the file name of the output instead, and open the file for writing in `run_mappers()`, adding a csv lock so that only 1 thread can have the `csv_writer` object at a time. I also ditched `concurrent.futures` and went with this nifty `Parallel` library. Not sure if this is entirely correct, but it's giving me the output I want...

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
csv_writer_lock = threading.Lock()

def run_mappers(individual_string, other_args, csv_filename):

   # long processing code goes here, ending up with processed_result 
   from_mapper.append(processed_result)
   # if file does not exist, create it and write
   else:
   with open(csv_filename, mode='a'):
       csv_writer.writerow(processed_result)

def parallelize_mappers(term_list, other_args, mapping_filename):
    n_workers = 2 * multiprocessing.cpu_count() - 1
    Parallel(n_jobs=n_workers,backend="multiprocessing")(
        delayed(run_mappers)
        (term, other_args, mapping_filename) 
  for term_pair in term_pair_list
  )
```